# Does the normal ubuntu Desktop 12.04.03 have a feature to partition the disk?

Tags: 12.04, installation, partitioning

The installation guides seem creepy. They never tell what is there in the advanced section of the live CD.
I want to format a partition as ext4fs or lower and then install Ubuntu.
Or perhaps install ubuntu in a different partition than that of Windoze.

Will the Ubuntu 12.04.03 CD Desktop allow me to do that?

P.S: and no, I can't download the alternate CD

Answer (score 0):

#### How to install Ubuntu 12.04.03 alongside Windows

If you run the standard graphical installer, it will suggest to install Ubuntu 12.04 alongside Windows. This will create a new partition with ext4 where Ubuntu will be installed and a partition for swap space.

If this is what you want to do there is to do the just use the standard installation step-by-step instructions [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GraphicalInstall)

Comment: Does the Install Ubuntu alongside them option create an ext4 partition?

Comment: Yes, [it does](http://askubuntu.com/questions/333717/ubuntu-12-04-02-filesystem).

Answer (score 0):

The ADVANCED selection from the installer presents you with a partition section where you can create all sorts of partitions for your Ubuntu install and tailor it to your needs...  Personally I use it to make a 10gb '/' partition for the filesystem and the rest of the hard-drive as '/home' for my files and settings, that way if I need to re-install for some reason, nothing is lost...

Answer (score 0):

yes. open gparted when ur booted from the live cd. manage your partitions. then install ubuntu wherever you want to.